# Lower bound with Currying - simplifiable?

Tags: scala, scalaz, currying, lower-bound

I'd like to wrap exceptions in an own error type leveraging scalazs disjunction.

Following code should compile

```
trait Result
trait Error extends Result
object MyError extends Error
object OK extends Result

val r: Error \/ OK.type = tryCatchIn(_ => MyError /*:Error*/) {
  val result: Error \/ OK.type = ???
  result
}
```

I'd like to keep the curried syntax and don't like to explicitly type `MyError`.

My current solution is twofold using

```
  def tryCatchIn2[L, R](exceptionTransformer: Throwable => L, `finally`: => Unit = () => ()): CatchFinally[L] = {
    new CatchFinally(exceptionTransformer, `finally`)
  }

  class CatchFinally[L](val exceptionTransformer: Throwable => L, `finally`: => Unit = () => ()) {
    def apply[L2 >: L, R](block: => L2 \/ R): L2 \/ R = try {
      block
    } catch {
      case NonFatal(e) => -\/(exceptionTransformer(e))
    } finally {
      `finally`
    }
  }
```

My initial, curried approach would reflect my intention much better, but I can **NOT** get it working:

```
  def tryCatchIn[L, R, L2 >: L](exceptionContainer: Throwable => L, `finally`: => Unit = () => ())
                               (block: => L2 \/ R): L2 \/ R = {
    try {
      block
    } catch {
      case NonFatal(e) => -\/(exceptionContainer(e))
    } finally {
      `finally`
    }
  }
```

Is a clearer solution possible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing some of your intentions but wouldn't this code be much simpler:

```
def tryCatchIn[L, R](exceptionContainer: Throwable => L, `finally`: => Unit = ())
                         (block: => R): L \/ R = {

    try {
        \/-(block)
    } catch {
        case NonFatal(e) => -\/(exceptionContainer(e))
    } finally {
       `finally`
    }
}
```

E.g. return only an `R`, finally is just `()` instead of `() => ()` and no need for type trickery. If you are even willing to dismiss the finally block you can do:

```
def catchMe[L,R](exceptionContainer: Throwable => L)(block: =>  R) : L \/ R = {
   Try {block}.toDisjunction.leftMap(exceptionContainer)
}
```

In case you want your solution to work you will need this function signature:

```
def tryCatchIn[L, R, L2 >: L](exceptionContainer: Throwable => L2, `finally`: => Unit = () => ())
                         (block: => L \/ R): L2 \/ R
```

because `\/` is defined as `\/[+A,+B]`. Using the `L2 :> L` trick is the solution, but you will also need to use the correct return type.

Comment: it doesn't infer the types correctly - try compiling the example code above

Comment: Hmm, I did. Even in an IntelliJ worksheet which usually fails miserably to infer types it works fine. 

```
val result = tryCatchIn(e => s"An exception occurred: ${e.getMessage}", println("finally"))(1/0)

val result2 = catchMe(e => s"An exception occurred: ${e.getMessage}")(1/0)
```

Both are inferred as String \/ Int.

Comment: did you try my example code starting at the 3rd line with `trait Result`, `object MyError` etc?

Comment: Edited the answer again.